# Replacing part of LaTeX command using BBedit grep

Tags: latex, substitution, bbedit

How can I use the BBedit grep option to replace LaTeX commands like

```
\textcolor{blue}{Some text}
```

by the contents of the second set of braces, so

```
Some text
```

?

Comment: This can be done in LaTeX by changing the definition of `\textcolor` to not use it's colour argument.

Comment: Of course, but I do not want my LaTeX commands littered with unnecessary `\textcolor` commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [BBEdit Grep Tutorial](https://anybrowser.org/bbedit/grep.html) gives a lot of information and good examples on using the grep option in BBEdit. What you are trying to achieve is actually a variation of one of the examples. The solution is to enter the following:

> Find: `\\textcolor\{blue\}\{([^\}]*)\}`
>
> Replace: `\1`

The relevant part is the "Find" section. The first part: `\\textcolor\{blue\}\{` basically searches for the content `\textcolor{blue}{`. You need the `\`s to escape special characters.

Next, we have the cryptic sequence `([^\}]*)`: The `(...)` saves everything inside the parentheses into the variable `\1`, which you can use in the "Replace" section to insert the content. The `[^\}]*` consists of `^\}` which means match all characters which are *not* `^` a closing brace `\}`. With `[...]*` we say, match any number of "not brace" characters. Overall, this expression makes the grep match all characters which are not closing braces, and saves them into `\1`.

Finally, the expression ends with a `\}`, i.e. a closing brace, which is the end of what we want to find.

The "Replace" only contains `\1`, which is everything inside the parentheses `(...)` in the "Find" field.